# JQuery UI Datepicker - MaxDate exclude disabled days

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datepicker

I am trying to **exclude disabled dates** when **counting MaxDate**.
I tried many ways but still doesn't work.
Any suggestion?

**02-12-2019** and **Sundays** has been **disabled** but the **Maxdate include the disabled date**.
Maxdate should be **3 days** which excludes disabled days and Maxdays starts by today.
My goal is to add days if the days between today until max days has disabled.
**Add 1 day per disabled day**

**Update**

Now i am able to Exclude sunday when counting maxdate but i still can't exclude the array date where it should add one more day after 02-12-2019.

**Updated Code** :(

```
<script>
var array = ["02-12-2019"]

//new

function includeDate(date) {

    return date.getDay() !== 7 && date.getDay() !== 0;
}

function getTomorrow(date) {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1);
}

//prev

    $('input').datepicker(
        {
      defaultDate: "+1d",
      inline: true,
      showOtherMonths: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      required: true,
      showOn: "focus",
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: 1,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
         var isDisabled = ($.inArray(string, array) != -1);
        return [includeDate(date)  && !isDisabled];
    },

    maxDate: (function(max) {
        var today = new Date();
        var nextAvailable = getTomorrow(today);
        var count = 0;
        var countz = 1;
        var newMax = 0;
        while(count < max) {
            if (includeDate(nextAvailable) ) {
                count++;
            }
            if (includeDate(nextAvailable) ) {
                countz++;
            }
            newMax++;
            nextAvailable = getTomorrow(nextAvailable);            
        }
        return newMax;
    })
    (3)
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3o1dmvw5/96/

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to do. `Maxdate should be 3 days` - do you mean `maxDate` should be 3 days from today?  And that `maxDate` should be clickable, even if it was otherwise disabled?

Comment: One comment - you are initialising `$('#datepicker2')` in your `$('#datepicker1')` change handler, so it will be initialised multiple times.  You should initialise it just once, and then [change options with the option method](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option).

Comment: Also, what does `$holidays` look like?  What is `config('app.date_format_js')`? Does `#datepicker2` have anything to do with your question (disabled `maxDate`)?  Please see [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - you could edit out a lot of this code, add in the real `config()` value, so we could see working code and try debugging it.

Comment: Hey @Don'tPanic thanks! I have just updated my Question. My Goal is to add days if the days between today until maxdays has disabled days.
Add 1 day per disabled day. My jquery works fine but i can't add days if the date range between mindate and maxdate has disabled date. Is there any way to make any condition? Thanks again!

Comment: config('app.date_format_js') is a format for date in config/app file.

Comment: I know what it means, but I don't know what you have in your `config/app.php` file.  We can't run your code, because we don't have your `config/app.php`.  For this question, it is not relevant that you are using Laravel - we just need to know what that value is - you could remove it and replace it with `"Y-m-d"` (or whatever it really is).  Same for `$holidays` - just give us a small hardcoded array which demonstrates the problem.  Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic :) I have simplified the codes. Please have a look at the question and jsfiddle. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic i have make an update to the question. Please help if possible. Thank you :)

Comment: I was playing with this yesterday in JSFiddle, but wasn't able to get it working.  `beforeShow()` sounds like the right place to do the work but AFAICT it actually runs *before* all the `beforeShowDay()` calls :-(

Comment: Alright bro. Thanks anyway. I have updated my JSFiddle @Don'tPanic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below should be the solution. The problem with your code is that you forgot to verify the date string to see if it is in the array or not using your includeDate() function. Thus, your includeDate() function allow that date, while maxDate didn't allow that date.

Also, you can also use array.indexOf() instead of jQuery's inArray. I am pretty sure that native array.indexOf() probably is faster.

Besides that, I modify your maxDate() function a little bit. It now look less confusing. I used window onload so that I can debug the code easy. You can just take that out.

For my version, when it come to verify the days, beforeShowDay and includeDate does the same thing. Thus, I edited beforeShowDay() to just return the value from the function includeDate().

Also, you should change the input selector to an ID(#) or Class(.). Otherwise, your datepicker will proc on all input fields.

Also, I modified you includeDate() function. There isn't a day 7 as 0 - 6 = Sunday - Saturday.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
var array = ["02-12-2019"]

//new

function includeDate(date) {
    var dateStr = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
    // Date 0 = Sunday & 6 = Saturday
    return date.getDay() !== 0 && array.indexOf(dateStr) === -1;
}

function getTomorrow(date) {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1);
}

//prev
window.onload = function(){
    $('input').datepicker(
        {
      defaultDate: "+1d",
      inline: true,
      showOtherMonths: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      required: true,
      showOn: "focus",
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: 1,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [includeDate(date)];
    },

    maxDate: (function(max) {
        // Next available is today at first.
        var nextAvailable = new Date();
        var count = 0;
        var extra = 0;
        while(count < max) {
            /*
             * Next available is here so that getTomorrow does not need
             * to run an extra time when the loop is completed.
             *
             */
            nextAvailable = getTomorrow(nextAvailable);            
            // If the day is not available then we need to add an extra day.
            if ( !includeDate(nextAvailable) ) {
                extra++;
            // Else we just increase the count.
            } else {
                count++;
            }            
        }
        
        // Return max + extra.
        return max + extra;
    })
    (3)
    });
};
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: Bro please help me with this when ur free :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133641/jquery-ui-datepicker-dependent-datepicker-exclude-holidays-in-maxdate