# Jquery UI Datepicker - Dependent Datepicker Exclude Holidays in Maxdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am trying to exclude **Array Dates** and  **Sundays** in Dependent Datepicker.
The **first datepicker** works really well while the **second datepicker** doesn't exclude Array dates and sundays in Maxdate.
Second datepicker must selectable within 7 working days which should exclude Sunday and Array Dates.
I believe there's should be an easy way to achieve this.

Any Suggestion?

Here's the code :(

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var d = new Date();
    var array = ["10-12-2019","05-12-2019"];

    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    today = monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + d.getFullYear();
function includeDate(date) {

    var dateStr = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
    // Date 0 = Sunday & 6 = Saturday
    return date.getDay() !== 0 && array.indexOf(dateStr) === -1;
}
function getTomorrow(date) {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1);
}
    $('#datepicker2').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker(
        {
      defaultDate: "+1d",
      inline: true,
      showOtherMonths: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      required: true,
      showOn: "focus",
      numberOfMonths: 1,

      minDate: 1,
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [includeDate(date)];
    },
    maxDate: (function(max) {
        var nextAvailable = new Date();
        var count = 0;
        var extra = 0;
        while(count < max) {
            nextAvailable = getTomorrow(nextAvailable);             
            if ( !includeDate(nextAvailable) ) {
                extra++;  
            } else {
                count++;
            }            
        }
        return max + extra;
    })
    (3)   
});
    $('#datepicker1').change(function () {

        var from = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
        var date_diff = Math.ceil((from.getTime() - Date.parse(today)) / 86400000);
        var maxDate_d = date_diff + 7 +'d';
        date_diff = date_diff + 'd';
        $('#datepicker2').val('').removeAttr('readonly').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
            inline: true,
      showOtherMonths: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      required: true,
      showOn: "focus",
      numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: date_diff +1,
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [includeDate(date)];
    },
    maxDate: (function(max) {
        var nextAvailable = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
        var count = 0;
        var extra = 0;
        while(count < max) {
            nextAvailable = getTomorrow(nextAvailable);             
            if ( !includeDate(nextAvailable) ) {
                extra++;  
            } else {
                count++;
            }            
        }
        return max + extra;
    })
    (7)
}); 
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLveychs/83/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your code, it is almost right. You just forgot one thing for the second date picker. That is, you did not add the date_diff value to the return value of the maxDate() anonymous function. I was going to pass the date_diff by adding it to the parameter. Nonetheless, I found a bug. It can't be done that way, because any previous un-selectable days, will turn into additional extra days. Thus, the only way to add date_diff is start from the day of date picker1 and add the return value of maxDate's anonymous function to date_diff.

I also took out some unnecessary codes. You can just get the date differences simply subtracting datepicker1 date to today date without needing to parse a date string. Plus, date_diff can be as was without needing a "d" to be added to it.

Also, take note that, when you calculate the different days between two dates, for your code, it work that way, because datepicker's date picked object is set to the 0 hour of the day. That code may not work for other scenario. The for sure way to get the day difference between two dates is by setting their hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds(if needed) to zeroes.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var array = ["10-12-2019","05-12-2019"];
   
    function includeDate(date) {
        var dateStr = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
        // Date 0 = Sunday & 6 = Saturday
        return date.getDay() !== 0 && array.indexOf(dateStr) === -1;
    }

    function getTomorrow(date) {
        return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    
    $('#datepicker2').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker(
        {
      defaultDate: "+1d",
      inline: true,
      showOtherMonths: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      required: true,
      showOn: "focus",
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: 1,
      
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [includeDate(date)];
    },
    maxDate: (function(max) {
        var nextAvailable = new Date();
        var count = 0;
        var extra = 0;
        while(count < max) {
            nextAvailable = getTomorrow(nextAvailable);             
            if ( !includeDate(nextAvailable) ) {
                extra++;  
            } else {
                count++;
            }            
        }
        return max + extra;
    })
    (3)   
});
    $('#datepicker1').change(function () {
        var from = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
        // Date diff can be obtained like this without needing to parse a date string.
        var date_diff = Math.ceil((from - new Date()) / 86400000);
        
        $('#datepicker2').val('').removeAttr('readonly').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
            inline: true,
      showOtherMonths: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      required: true,
      showOn: "focus",
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: date_diff + 1,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      return [includeDate(date)];
    },
    
    maxDate: (function(max) {
        var nextAvailable = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
        var count = 0;
        var extra = 0;
        while(count < max) {
            nextAvailable = getTomorrow(nextAvailable);             
            if ( !includeDate(nextAvailable) ) {
                extra++;
            } else {
                count++;
            }            
        }
        /*
         * Date diffent have to be added to return value.
         */
        return max + date_diff + extra;
    })
    (7)
}); 
    });

});
</script>

<p>datepicker1 <input id="datepicker1"></p>
<p>datepicker2 <input id="datepicker2"></p>
```

Comment: @Suvin94 - You are welcome and check out the fixed code. I found a bug in the previous code. It shouldn't have any bug now. You can test select the previous code on Dec 6 and this new code the same day to see the differences.

Comment: Damn bro. You're amazing. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Hey bro! Help me with this if ur free https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677125/jquery-datepicker-autofill-date-based-on-first-date-without-select

Comment: @Steven94 - I probably can help you in a couple days if no one help you yet.

Comment: Okay bro sure :)

Comment: @Steven94 - I answered your question.